# Mismatch in SOAP/SAAJ dependencies in WAS 8.5

Tags: java, soap, websphere-8

I've been trying to upgrade to Spring 5 and I am having issues with the SAAJ wrapper around my SOAP web services.  It all works fine on tomcat, but moving it to WAS 8.5 has caused me no end of trouble.

The following is the stack trace that is generated when migrating.

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[appServlet]: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent; class=com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl, method=createDocumentFragment()Lorg/w3c/dom/DocumentFragment;, pc=5; Type Mismatch, argument 0 in signature com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentFragment.<init>:(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/CoreDocumentImpl;)V does not match
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl.createDocumentFragment()Lorg/w3c/dom/DocumentFragment; @5: JBinvokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/CoreDocumentImpl'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @5
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl' }
    stack: { 'uninitialized', 'uninitialized', 'com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl' }
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.<init>(SOAPPartImpl.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.<init>(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70)
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.getSOAPPart(Message1_1Impl.java:96)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.getEnvelope(SaajSoapMessage.java:142)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getVersion(AbstractSoapMessage.java:89)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.<init>(SaajSoapMessage.java:118)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:176)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60)
    at org.springframework.ws.context.DefaultMessageContext.<init>(DefaultMessageContext.java:42)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:553)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.doHandle(SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.ws.AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway.java:210)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:165)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.lambda$configureChain$0(MessageHandlerChain.java:124)
    ...
```

These are the relevant (hopefully) dependencies in my pom.xml file.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Web & MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>opensaml-saml-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>opensaml-xacml-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
                <artifactId>opensaml-xacml-saml-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ORM/Build -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```